# Disable Max Zoom

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession

I'm making a camera and it has a pinch to zoom. I'm trying to find a way to disable the maximum zoom level. Here is my code...

```
func pinch(pinch: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

    let pinchVelocityDividerFactor:CGFloat = 10

    if pinch.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed {
        do {
            try device.lockForConfiguration()

            let desiredZoomFactor = device.videoZoomFactor + atan2(pinch.velocity, pinchVelocityDividerFactor)

            device.videoZoomFactor = max(1, min(desiredZoomFactor, device.activeFormat.videoMaxZoomFactor))

            device.unlockForConfiguration()

        } catch {
            // handle error
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to not have my camera have a max zoom like Snapchat? Thanks!